# Search bar when swiping down in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisearchbar

I am developing a social media app for **iOS**

My `ViewControllers` are currently embedded in a `NavigationController`. 
On my news feed screen, I need to display a search bar when the user swipes down (and hide it when he swipes up) in which if the user types something, the search results will be displayed on top of the news feed screen.

I have tried to tinker with this but I am pretty new to iOS and so far have not managed to get this to work.

Any help would grately be appreciated and keep in mind that I have only been programming iOS for a couple of weeks so some in-depth would be helpful.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll need to implement `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

include the `setup()` function in `viewDidAppear`

```
func setup() {
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(down))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(up))
    swipeUp.direction = .up

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40.0))
    if let searchBar = searchBar
    {
        searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
    }
}
```

Then your two functions up and down

```
func down(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("down")
    //show bar
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.searchBar!.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 64.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40.0)
    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
    })
}

func up(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("up")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.searchBar!.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40.0)
    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
    })
}
```

You can add `Bool isShowing` to avoid unnecessary animations. Then, implement the search bar delegate `textDidChange` to change the search results as the user types.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,textDidChange searchText: String)`
```

All you need to do now is display your results in a `UISearchController`.

**Note** 
Using swipe up/down motion might interfere with the scrolling of the `UIScreachController`